# Can you update value in ejs without rendering?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to figure out how to tell the user that the username is taken, but 
I have to re-render the page. When I render the page all of the clients side information disappears (username, password...). Is there a way to just update a single html tag without rendering the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

No that's not possible with ejs itself, You have to make an Ajax call to check the username and update the DOM on client-side.

Comment: Could you show me an example with ajax or send a link to redirect me to an example